# What book contains the rules for Riot Shields?

Tags: product-identification, shield, phoenix-command

So, I know there are no rules for riot shields in the basic nor advanced Small Arms Combat rules.  I'm wondering what supplement, if any, does contain rules and equipment for anti-ballistic shields.

The *Special Weapons Data Supplement* looks promising, but I don't own it and I can't find any information on its potential treatment of shields specifically, though it was marketed as:

> This Special Weapons Supplement to the Phoenix Command Combat System contains all the necessary rules and data for a wide variety of unusual or distinctive weapon systems, included are:
>
> ...
>
> - Riot Control Gear, from Tear Gas to Plastic Bullets

Does this supplement, in fact, contain riot shields?  If not, are there any supplements that do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the SWDS, but the *Phoenix Command Hand-to-Hand Combat System* does cover shields, and a riot shield would more or less be what it calls a "scutem".